# ListView.CheckedItems very slow

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a ListView containing 17.000+ items. When using ListView.SelectedItems to get data from say 100 items, it completes almost instantly.  But if I use ListView.CheckedItems instead to get data from the same items, it takes over one minute.  I'm using the exact same code in both cases.  Is this normal?

```
ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection selectedItems = listViewProducts.SelectedItems;

        for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems.Count; i++)
        {
            string sku = listViewProducts.Items[selectedItems[i].Index].SubItems[1].Text;
            string productName = listViewProducts.Items[selectedItems[i].Index].SubItems[0].Text;

            CurrentProductGroup.Add(sku + "|" + productName);
        }
```

OK, this works, getting data from 100 checked items takes about 2 seconds:

```
int numberOfItems = listViewProducts.Items.Count;

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++)
        {
            if (listViewProducts.Items[i].Checked)
            {
                string sku = listViewProducts.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text;
                string productName = listViewProducts.Items[i].Text;

                CurrentProductGroup.Add(sku + "|" + productName);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Use a DataGridView with an "extra" checkbox column and a datasource. But....no user can consume 17,000 items so why flood the UI with that many?

Comment: In this context it's necessary to list all 17.000+ items in many cases. And it's working fine in all other respects so I'm not much for rewriting a lot of code just for fixing this.

Comment: .. how is the user supposed to select choices from 17,000 items?

Comment: Scrolling the list and select those they want?

Comment: How long does scrolling a list of 17k items take? How reliable is the selection going to be? You need to rethink your UI.

Comment: The users like it that way, actually.  It's not items they're supposed to purchase, it's a catalog of items they already have purchased.

Comment: But I've found a solution that's just as fast as with SelectedItems.  Will add the code.

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp, In reference to your claim that "no user can consume 17,000 items"...are you a C++ developer by chance?  `winuser.h` has ~16,000 lines of code that open just fine in a text editor.  Would you rather this file did not open in your editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is overly complicated.

```
ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection selectedItems = listViewProducts.SelectedItems;

foreach (ListViewItem item in selectedItems)
{
    string sku = item.SubItems[1].Text;
    string productName = item.SubItems[0].Text;

    CurrentProductGroup.Add(sku + "|" + productName);
}
```

Disclaimer: untested code as I don't have your dataset available.

Comment: Yes, almost the same solution I found.  I just didn't think of this at first since it worked fine with SelectedItems.  Thanks!

Comment: Why do you insist on incurring the cost of an index lookup since you already have the items themselves in the list?

Comment: Yea, you're right. I guess the problem is that there are so many ways what work, that if something works and is fast enough you don't always check if it can be done in a better way.

Comment: Agreed, but in this case, looking up the item per index, when you already have the items in the selecteditems list is obviously what we call a "code smell"

Comment: Your first one I guess. I had not refreshed the page. Looking at your second sample, I'd say is even worse, cause now you dereference the index 3 times ;-)